# Looking for nontrivial examples for the 3D wave equation

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics, publishing

We have developed a (new) numerical scheme to solve the classical wave equation in 3 dimensions and we aim to publish the results.

We can read in the aim and scope of the journal of computational and applied mathematics :

" ...The computational efficiency (e.g. the convergence, stability, accuracy, ...) should be proved and illustrated by nontrivial numerical examples"

Immediately we can raise the question : What are known (or classical) nontrivial examples of exact solutions of the 3D wave equation? by that I mean the Cauchy problem :
$$u_{tt}=c^2\Delta u,\quad u(X,0)= f(X),\quad u_t(X,0)= g(X)$$
Nontrivial examples against which we can compare the results of the numerical scheme, that is, we need given $f$ and $g$, along with a 'computable' formula for $u(X,t)= u(x,y,z,t)$

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/seismic-wave-propagation

Comment: Use whatever smooth functions $F,G$ you want and set
$$u(r,t)=\frac{1}{r}(F(r-ct)+G(r+ct))$$

Comment: The example you provided is for radially symmetrical waves and it is trivial in my sense, I am looking for more complicated waves where $u(x,t)$ doesn't depend only on $r$.